# Trying to format multiplication table in Python

Tags: python, multiplication

Okay so I'm working on an assignment for my Python class. The professor wants me to make a multiplication table using the % format specifier.

```
x = 0
y = 0

for y in range(1, 11):
    for z in range(1, 11):
        print("%10i" %(y*z))
```

I know the format specifier is wrong, but how can I make it look like a multiplication table using the type of formatting in my code?

I want it to look like:

```
1 2 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
2 4 6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
. . .
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for y in range(1, 11):
    for z in range(1, 11):
        print(" %3i" %(y*z), end="")
    print("")
```

You don't need to initialize the variables, since `for` does that.

`%3i` is wide enough for all the values in this table; `%10i` will make the table extremely wide.

`end=""` keeps it from adding a newline after each number is printed, so all the numbers for the same value of `y` will be printed on the same row. Then `print("")` adds a newline at the end of the row.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/y7aDHL)

Answer (score 1):

I think your task would be easier if you used list comprehensions. Or moved the `z` into the print statement:

```
for y in range(1, 11):
    print("%10i"*10 % tuple(z*y for z in range(1, 11)))
```

However, you could build the output string:

```
for y in range(1, 11):
    out = ""
    for z in range(1, 11):
         out += "%10i" % y*z
    print (out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there!
First, you don't need `x` and `y` variables.  You two loops are OK.  Second, since the largest number you will print is 100, you need to print each number at least three characters long (use `"%3d"` for that).  Third, to prevent print from writing each number on a separate line, put a comma at the end.  You will have to insert another `print` to change lines after the inner loop.

```
for y in range(1, 11):
  for z in range(1, 11):
    print("%3d" %(y*z)),
  print ("")
```

My answer assumes python2.  For python3, the comma after the print will not prevent line break, use `print("%4d" %(y*z), end="")` instead.  And increase width to four characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
x = 0
y = 0
s="";

for y in range(1, 11):
    for z in range(1, 11):
        s=s+"  "+str(y*z)
    s=s+"\n"
  
print(s);
```

Comment: Did you test this code? It doesn't run. There are several errors in it.

Comment: You can also take help from my articles

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/python-for-loop553/
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/patterns-in-python/
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/members/sourabh-somani/articles

Comment: you can remove semicolons and check, I have tested this it is working

Comment: Also check my articles you will get what I have done please check that

Comment: `str=str+"  "+(y*z))` You have an extra parentheses. Also, `str` is a builtin for the `str` method and you initialized `str = ""`, which clearly makes it a string, and then you are trying to add a string to an int here `str=str+"  "+(y*z))`. I really have no idea how that code is running on your end.

Comment: ohh remove last paranthesis

Comment: use this line
str=str+" "+(y*z)

Comment: There is also the fact that you didn't follow the OP requirements by using the `%` operator.

Comment: I have done type conversion 
use like this str=str+"  "+str(y*z)

Comment: use this 
str=str+" "+str(y*z)

Comment: Once again. Like I said, you overrode the builtin `str` method when you did `str = ""`. So If I run your line above you get: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Ok do one thing Last modify str to s

Comment: I have modified my source code one more time hope this time it will work

Comment: Could you make this code without the "\n"? I really don't understand what that means. Thank you.

Comment: I have used \n because after inner loop you want one enter